# Passing Array in C Function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am a beginner in c programming.  I have a program that counts letters in a txt file and stores the count in an array.  When I do the looping and counting in my main function everything works properly

```
#define SIZE  26
#define UPPERCASEA  65
#define LOWERCASEA  97
#define SHIFTCASE   32 //difference between 'A'(int 65) and 'a'(int 97)    

int main() {
    int letter = 0;
    int letters[SIZE] = {0};

    printInstructions();

    // loopAndCountLetters(letters);

    letter = getchar();

    // get rest of characters until EOF
    while (letter != EOF) {     
        // if necessary change to uppercase
        letter = changeToUpperCase(letter);

        // increment proper letter in array
        letters[letter - UPPERCASEA]++;

        // get next letter
        letter = getchar();
    } // end of while

    printLetterArray(letters, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

However if I take the same code and try to put it into a function and pass my array to that function I get `Bus Error (core dumped)`. Function below:

Function call in main function:

```
loopAndCountLetters(letters);
```

Function definition:

```
void loopAndCountLetters(int array[]) {
    int letter = 0;

    letter = getchar();

    // get rest of characters until EOF
    while (letter != EOF) { 
        // if necessary change to uppercase
        if (letter >= LOWERCASEA) {
            // shift value to uppercase
            letter = letter - SHIFTCASE;
        }

        // increment letter in array
        array[letter - UPPERCASEA]++;

        letter = getchar();
    } //end of while

    return;
}
```

Example of sentence that works properly:

> This works properly.
>
> even this works? Yes it does.

This causes error

> Anything with a colon: causes error

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and include all macros and other definitions that you have currently left out. For example, what is `SIZE`? Or `LOWERCASEA` and `UPPERCASEA`? Or `SHIFTCASE`?

Comment: And why don't you simply use [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)?

Comment: Post the definitions of all symbols.  The code in the function differs from the previous code in `main`.

Comment: Lastly a note about your use of comments: Using comments to describe parts of the code that's hard to understand, or to describe what different functions do, comments like "define variable" or "increment letter in array" are pretty much useless, and only adds noise to the code which makes it harder to read. There's no need to add comments to things that are obvious for anyone  with even a smallest amount of knowledge of C, or for absolutely trivial things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree, this is for a class and that is what the professor has requested, i could remove them for clarity on SO

Comment: And just because something is *seemingly* working fine in one context doesn't mean it's alright. One of the possibilities of *undefined behavior* is to actually seem to work fine, but it's still an error. Also, enable plenty ow warnings, as the compiler then may tell you about things that is thinks are strange or might cause UB. And without seeing an MCVE it's impossible to do anything but *guess* (and guess badly).

Comment: Why are you using macros for the characters? You can write `'A'` and `'a'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here my ***guess***, and it assumes that `UPPERCASEA` is equal to `'A'` (or its [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) equivalent).

The problem is then when you do `letter-UPPERCASEA` for almost everything that is not an actual letter, you will get a *negative* index, which will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Lets take the example with the colon `':'`. It's ASCII value is `58`. The ASCII encoding of `'A'` is `65`. So when you do

```
array[letter-UPPERCASEA]++;
```

it's actually the same as doing

```
array[58-65]++;
```

which is equal to

```
array[-7]++;
```

You should filter out any non-letters before indexing in the array.

And before you ask, it just *seems* to work in the `main` function. In reality it really doesn't.

Comment: in the main function what happens when you reference a negative index? and what about the question mark, that would be array[63-65] which would be the same behavior?

Comment: @KailuaBum The exact same thing that happens when you do it in a separate function: [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just don't do it, *anywhere*.

Comment: in the main function, the last sentence including the colon does not produce an error.  it counts all of the letters

Comment: @KailuaBum You clearly don't read what I write. Negative indexes leads to UB, UB might sometime ***seem*** to work, but don't do anything that leads to UB anyway as it is ***bad***. And without a MCVE it's ***impossible*** to give a proper answer, all we can do is guess which is what my answer is.

Comment: It appears as though in the main function that the negative indexes were not causing problems, but for some reason the colon specifically in the other function was causing the problem.  Once i corrected the indexes (in range of array size), things appear to be working.  Thanks for your help